# Scala class constructor default arguments with expression using previous members

Tags: scala, syntax

I'd want to create a class (or better case class) which would behave like this:

```
case class MyClass(n: Int, m: Int = 2 * n)
```

So that `m` could have default value based on `n`. But seems it is impossible, scala says: `not found: value n`. First idea is to write `m: Int = -1` and mutate it in constructor if it's still -1, but it is `val`. And now I have no any other ideas.

Maybe anybody will shed some light on what's possible here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly provide a second factory:

```
case class MyClass(n: Int, m: Int)
object MyClass{
  def apply(n: Int): MyClass = MyClass(n, 2 * n)
}
```

Unlike when using 2 parameter lists as in @om-nom-nom's answer, the case class is unaffected, and in particular you can pattern match as usual to extract both `n` and `m`.

Comment: Thanks, that's good. om-nom-nom's variant with curryed constructor is also interesting though. (Answer deleted but there were `case class MyClass(n: Int)(m: Int = 2 * n)`)

Answer (score 0):

You must define a companion object :

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class MyClass(n: Int, m: Int);

object MyClass {
def apply(n: Int) : MyClass = new MyClass(n, n * 2)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class MyClass
defined module MyClass

scala> MyClass(12);
res4: MyClass = MyClass(12,24)
```